# Recent Bitcoin fork/why didnt I get credit?

Tags: blockchain-fork

I am new to this crypto currency thing and am soooo confused but learn more and more everyday! What I am trying to figure out now is:

1. I own a fraction of a Bitcoin on Coinbase. I look at coin base as my “ETrade”. I can just buy and sell there, is there a better place and if so why is the other place better?
2. Recently, in November, Bitcoin had a fork. I was under the impression during a fork it is just like a “split”. I thought I would get equal “shares” of Bitcoin under a different symbol and/or Blockchain. I do not see where I received anything. Why?
3. Should I hold my coins elsewhere to take advantage of forks? If so, where?

Thank you so much for trying to clear up my spinning head!

Comment: https://support.coinbase.com/customer/portal/articles/2853600-bitcoin-cash---frequently-asked-questions

Answer (score 1):

If you had your coins in coinbase, you won't be credited as coinbase owns your private keys. To get your hard fork credits, you needed to have your funds in a external wallet with access to your private keys. After a fork happens, you can download a wallet that supports the new coin and import your private keys into it.